# Replace http links with anchor tag

Tags: javascript, regex

So i'm building a chat-client where i read the incoming-messages through json.

However, I would like to be able to convert URLs to clickable anchor-tags instead. I've looked around but haven't really found any posts asking or getting an answer about this.

This is my current code:

```
if (json.type === 'message') {
    var val;  
    var str = json.data.text; //message-string
    var here  = str.match("([^\s]+)"); // match any word until space <---| merge
if (!here.search(/^http[s]?:\/\//)){ //if it contains http / https   <---| these?
    val = '<a href=\"' + here + "\"> [Link] </a>";        
}
    addMessage(json.data.author, val, json.data.color, new Date(json.data.time));
}
else {
    console.log('Hmm..., I\'ve never seen JSON like this:', json);
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're never using `val`, but it would probably be a lot easier to use `replace` immediately. You may want to add `target="_blank"` to ensure that the links open in a *new* window rather than replacing the chat page. (the `target="_blank"` seems not to work in embedded snippet due to sandboxing, but it works on an ordinary page)

```js
const text = 'here is a message with a link to https://www.google.com and another link to https://stackoverflow.com';
const changedText = text.replace(
  /(https?:\/\/)([^ ]+)/g,
  '<a target="_blank" href="$&">$2</a>'
);
console.log(changedText);

document.body.innerHTML += changedText;
```